# Assign diagnostic category based on diagnostic codes of several rows

Tags: r, for-loop, categorization

I have a dataset with 5235 patients, each in its own row with a variable number of diagnostic codes from columns 2:88 (some patients have 1 code, others 2, and so on). Each has its own ID as well.

I have a list of codes (e.g. influenza = 29, 38, 40). I am trying to assign an indicator variable influenza = 1 if ANY of the codes (29, 38, 40) are present. And influenza = 0 if non of the codes are present.

I first created a vector with the rows that contain diagnostic codes

```
varlist <- DXE[,2:88]
```

Then I used a for loop, to look on the entire dataset.

```
for (col in varlist) { if (29 | 38 | 40 %in% varlist){ DXE$influenza == 1} else{DXE$influenza == 0}}
```

Nevertheless, when I look at the output, the entire "influenza" row = 1.

Comment: Can you provide some data? There are guidelines about minimal reproducible data.

Comment: Agree you need to add sample data and desired output.  Looking at your example it appears you are mixing your logic of your `if` statement.  Most likely you want something like `col %in% c(29, 38, 40)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to assign a patient to be 1 if it has one of the influenza codes and 0 if there's none, you can simply make a boolean matrix, and find the rowMeans. Any rowMeans > 0 will give you 1, because in at least one of the columns, there is a influenza entry

```
#simulate data
DXE = data.frame(ID=1:5235,
matrix(sample(1:200,5235*87,replace=TRUE),ncol=87))
head(DXE)
influenza_code = c(29,38,40)
DXE$influenza = as.numeric(rowMeans(DXE[,2:88]==29 | DXE[,2:88]==38 | DXE[,2:88]==40)>0)
```